# Call the Resource name for TextBlock control in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, asp.net-mvc-4

i am new to Windows store app. now i created the folder for the resource file for French[Strings -> fr-FR ->Resources.resw] and English[Strings -> en-US ->Resources.resw].
and declared the Heading1="hdFREN" and Heading1="hdENG" respectively.

now i have to call the Heading1 to the TextBlock text="".. How to declare the text in the TextBlock control???

Comment: <TextBlock Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.Heading1, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"/> .. i declared this for Windows Phone App but it is not working in Windows Store App..

Answer (score 0):

Actually i created the resources.resw in the root folder [Strings -> fr-FR ->Resources.resw] and English[Strings -> en-US ->Resources.resw]. then i am creating manually LocalizedStrings

```
enter code here
```

public class LocalizedStrings
{

```
private static Resources _localizedResources = new Resources();

public Resources LocalizedResources { get { return _localizedResources; } }
```

}

now i can't call that Resources file. it is showing error

Answer (score 0):

This is a an overview of localization, and should address most of your questions.

[Quickstart: Translating UI resources (Windows Store apps using C#/VB/C++ and XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Hh965329%28v=win.10%29.aspx)